# Bazaar plugin for Anjuta

Tags: development, launchpad, bazaar, anjuta

I want to use Anjuta for development and Bazaar for version control. But the launchpad project listed on this page is empty.

http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/IDEIntegration

Is it dead? Is there another plugin?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there aren't any other Anjuta integration projects for Bazaar.

The original author of anjuta-bazaar requested the project be set to inactive: https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad-registry/+question/128171

It'd be great if somebody could pick up where he left the project and improve it. If there's anything I can help with from the Bazaar side, let me know.

Comment: Did you see if there was anything useful in the launchpad code I linked to?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but from looking at it it seems like a reasonable starting point.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could find : 
https://code.launchpad.net/~cemsbr/anjuta-bazaar/python2.6

It's an update from the original project to use python2.6, though it will have to be built (after having installed GTK dev libraries and other bits).